# Is it possible to skip role removing using callbacks with rolify gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rolify

I use rolify in my Rails app and I'm trying to stop the process "remove role" with callback but it does not seem to do what I want.

rails 6.0.3 / rolify 5.3.0

this is my code

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify before_remove: :check_remove_role
  # ...
  def check_remove_role(role)
    puts 'Remove role'
    # Do not remove role if User is the only super_admin
    return false if role.name=='super_admin' && User.with_role(role.name).count == 1
  end
end
```

When I call user.remove_role(role) the callback pass, but the "removing process" does not stop even if the callback return 'false'.

Is there something wrong in my code ? or do I have to do it another way (maybe I can not use callback for this) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are hoping to use these callbacks like an ActiveRecord validation. They are different things. The callback is simply a way to run code before and after the role record is created/destroyed, it is not used to control whether the mutation code within is run.

Some options:

1. Add logic to your model to test if it `can_remove_role?(:role)` and then test that in your controller before making the change.
2. If you are saving from a form, you can make a validation on the model to check your condition. ie. The User model would be invalid if that was what changed. Check out the methods on Dirty for inspiration on how to see what did/will change https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html
3. Use a policy in something like the Pundit gem or similar authorization package (which your program should have if it is to be used in a real environment) to wrap changing of roles. ie. in the Pundit example your UserPolicy would have a `change_role?` or similar policy where you define what is a legal role change for the `@record` and then call the authorize on it.

Option 3 is nice, because it provides a DRY location to make more rules regarding what can and cannot be done with your Users. Perhaps do some searches for tutorials on how Pundit and Rolify can be used together.

Comment: PS. a pattern I like for when a User can have more than one role, is to add a collection of roles to your form (checkboxes), then add to your create? and update? policies to see if all role conditions are valid, finally add the `authorize @user` line to create/update actions. done easy.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking callbacks should work like Rails active record callbacks. I use pundit with rolify in my application, so I will follow your suggestion of option 3 (first I thought to integrate code such as option 1, but option 3 seems very interresting). Thank you very much for your detailed answer !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like callbacks won't help you. According to [wiki](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Usage)

```
    Trying to remove a global role where the user has a role with the same name on a resource will remove that scoped role (whatever the scope is)
    Trying to remove a class scoped role where the user has an instance scoped role with the same name on a resource will remove that instance scoped role
    Trying to remove a role scoped to a resource class where the user has a global role won't remove it
    Trying to remove a role scoped to a resource instance where the user has a global role won't remove it
```